# Image tag src attribute not working in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am creating a Google chart in wordpress, chart is rendered and stored into an image. However I am not able to call the image using `<img src="" />`. Following is the code:

```
$filepath = "/wp-content/uploads/graph.png";

file_put_contents($filepath, $response);

echo $filepath;

echo "<img src=\"/wp-content/uploads/graph.png\">";
```

I have also tried with http://*/graph.png which is not working. If I open the same in different browser, image is showing properly.

Comment: `$filepath` is likely to be incorrect - you need to use an absolute, internal filesystem path

Comment: You could try using `wp_upload_dir()` to get an absolute path for your upload, checkout http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_upload_dir

Comment: *"If i open the same in different browser, image is showing properly."* <-- what do you mean? If you navigate manually to http://yoursite.com/wp-content/uploads/graph.png, do you see the image? I believe this is treated as a relative path, so if you try to include the file from http://yoursite.com/my/blog/, it'll try to load the image from http://yoursite.com/my/blog/wp-content/uploads/graph.png. Make sure the file is uploaded in the right location. Make sure that you are either having an absolute url to the location of the image or a valid relative location.

Comment: @Pekka웃 is right. to check your current directory use or pure php function getcwd(). Note that if you develop in wordpress you should use constants WP_CONTENT_DIR and WP_CONTENT_URL

Comment: Try adding $filepath = "../../wp-content/uploads/graph.png";

Comment: Well, i worked it out. I have just created an IMG SRC outside of the PHP with relative fixed path. Its working. Thanks guys for the efforts. I know this is not the best way, but solves the purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
echo '<img src="' . get_bloginfo('template_directory') . '/images/logo.gif" />';
```

Go for 'template_directory' or 'stylesheet_directory'.

Comment: echo '<img src="' . get_bloginfo('template_directory') . '/images/logo.gif" />';

Comment: I edited your answer so that the code snippet shows up properly now. StackOverflow uses 4-space indent rather than `<code>` tags. So no worries.

Answer (score 0):

You may try the below code;

Much better if you combine your HTML code and PHP code. Much cleaner easy to read.

PHP code

```
<?php
    Try changing your file path to
    $filepath = "../../wp-content/uploads/graph.png";
    file_put_contents($filepath, $response);
?>
```

HTML Code

```
<img src="<?php echo $filepath; ?>"/>
```

Comment: `var_dump($filepath)` is always going to be `/wp-content/uploads/graph.png`. How is that going to help?